# What effects does the blood moon event have on the world, other than respawning monsters?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

**Aside from respawning monsters, how does the blood moon event affect the world?**

I've heard rumours that cooking during the blood moon event causes a guaranteed critical cook. However, I'm unsure if this is true.

Comment: http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Blood_Moon  Critical cook appears to happen only between 11:30pm and 12:00am during a blood moon.  It's been discussed here the cooking during a blood moon also grants a random effect on all cooked food.

Comment: @TimmyJim Interesting, I tried cooking lots of stuff throughout the blood moon a while ago and I got mixed results iirc. I'll try again later though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Blood Moon has [4 main features](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Blood_Moon):

1) **Respawning Enemies** - As you've mentioned in your question, the Blood Moon causes monsters and guardians to come back to life (including monsters and guardians in shrines). This is useful for farming enemy parts (like Lynels), but be careful of minibosses or bosses who will regain their health after the Blood Moon ends.

2) **Weapon, Ingredient Respawns** - Weapons, items (like ores), and enemy encampment chests will also respawn during a Blood Moon. *Certain* ingredients also respawn after a Blood Moon (like fruits and mushrooms), though ingredients will also respawn anyway after a few days.

3) **Cooking Bonuses** - After 11:30pm, and before the ending cinematic at 12am, anything cooked will automatically result in a critical success. Critical successes include:

- 3 extra hearts
- An extra yellow heart
- An extra 2/5 stamina wheel
- An extra yellow stamina wheel
- Increased effect duration
- Effect level is raised by 1

4) **NPC Behaviour** - Some NPC's will behave oddly during a Blood Moon (eg Hino at [Dueling Peaks Stable](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Dueling_Peaks)), though it is unclear of any of this behaviour is significant in any meaningful way.

Comment: From my tests, ingredients do not respawn during/after the blood moon. I have gone to the Kakariko Great Fairy and harvested all the nearby Endura carrots, had a blood moon the next night, and the carrots had not respawned. This has happened to me at least three times - I check back on the carrots frequently since cooking 5 of them at once yields a dish worth ~400 rupees.

Comment: Interesting, I'll run a test of my own to confirm this after work today. I was admittedly going off the wiki for my answer - the wiki does specify fruits and mushrooms respawning in particular, and I'm happy to edit my answer above to reflect this should it be the case.

Comment: does it really upgrade the enemies too, making them tougher to kill?

Comment: I'm not sure that they're upgraded, I think they just respawn

Comment: @Jeffrey04 The enemies seem to get tougher through out the game as you pass certain milestones (most likely the number of divine beasts defeated but quite possibly things like number of shrines too) presumably the blood moon does play some part in this (either making dead enemies more powerful or upgrading any eligible enemies to higher level versions)

Answer (score 3):

Not a guaranteed critical cook, but you do get a higher chance of getting a bonus effect. It doesn't always make sense (I.e. Cooking 5 hearty durians can yield a simmered fruit that provides 21 bonus hearts) but you can always sell those items for more too. Also, don't forget that the blood moon regenerates ores as well!

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is great info but I will probably leave the question unanswered until an answer with a definitive list of everything is available. No hard feelings!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, there is a shrine quest associated with the moment a blood moon happens. You can get it from Kass near Ridgeland Tower in an area called Washa's Bluff. The quest is called "Under a Red Moon". [Walkthrough can be found here.](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/26/15065778/under-a-red-moon-shrine-quest-walkthrough-mijah-rokee-shrine-location)