# Where can I get guardian shields?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was watching videos for tips to defeating Guardians in BotW and I found this video of [guardian being defeated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbNxuEnfQ9E) purely by reflecting damage back at itself. I know that you can do this with a well timed parry with any shield, but with the Guardian Shield it looks like you don't have to parry at all.

[image: Reflecting a Guardian attack]

The only problem is, where can I get a Guardian Shield? I got one from a minor test of strength in a shrine, but it broke. Where can I get them reliably?

Find me a Guardian Shield

[image: Guardian Shield]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Shield), Guardian shields can be reliably found at both the [Soh Kofi Shrine](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Soh_Kofi_Shrine) and the [Pumaag Nitae Shrine](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Pumaag_Nitae_Shrine) after completing "A Minor Test of Strength".

Alternatively, [this wiki](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Guardian_Shield) lists the locations where Guardian Shields more generally can be found.

Guardian Shield: [West Necluda](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Dueling_Peaks), [Lanayru Great Spring](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Lanayru_Great_Spring)

Guardian Shield +: [East Necluda](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Hateno), [Faron Grasslands](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Faron_Grasslands)

Guardian Shield ++: [Gerudo Highlands](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Gerudo_Highlands), [Akkala Highlands](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Akkala)

In all of these areas, the Guardian Shield can be obtained by killing [Guardian Scouts](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Scout).

As I mentioned in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/308629/82710) to another Breath of the Wild question, Guardian Scouts will respawn after a [Blood Moon event](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Blood_Moon).

So strategically, I would visit the areas listed above, and make a point of targeting the Guardian Scouts, as it are these scouts which will drop the Guardian shields you are coveting. You can read about the strategy for efficiently defeating Guardian Scouts [here](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Scout). These enemies (both inside and outside of shrines) will respawn after a Blood Moon.

Comment: "I would visit the areas listed above, and make a point of targeting the Guardian Scouts": The source wiki page is somewhat unclear, but I believe it's specifically referring to the "Test of Strength" shrines in those respective areas. For example, the Guardian Shield++ is carried by the Guardian Scout IVs in the Tutsuwa Nima (Akkala Highlands) and Kema Kosassa (Gerudo Highlands) shrines. You're not going to find Guardian Scouts out in the overworld, outside of shrines.

Answer (score 8):

The regular Guardian shield (which is what is pictured in your screenshot) *does not* automatically reflect most Guardian beams. Only the Guardian Shield++, which is only obtainable from Major Tests of Strength, can reflect Guardian *scout* beams - that is, only the lasers from the Guardian enemies in shrines. Lasers from Decayed, Stalker, Flying, and Sentry Guardians will still only be deflected sideways, and your shield will break if the durability is low enough. Source: [Zelda Wikia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian_Shield), [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75109631)

If you want a shield that auto-reflects even the stronger lasers, you'll need to get an Ancient Shield from the Akkala research facility. It's quite expensive though, costing 1 giant ancient core plus other resources, and it can only auto-reflect 5 lasers before breaking on the sixth (Source: [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75133450)). My recommendation is to learn the timing to parry the laser beams, as that will save a lot of shield durability and won't waste resources.

Comment: I'm not to sure on the only 5 laser deflect remark. I went through the entirety of Hyrule Castle with one Ancient Shield, I can assure you that I sometimes took more than 5 lasers in one encounter, let alone the entire castle.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest place to get them *is* at the test of strength shrines. Though, you'll get more than just guardian shields but also other guardian weapons.

As for strategies for tests of strength, I find that easiest way to fight them is to use your strongest axe weapon and charge your attack (but never releasing). Let the axe rotations hit them and deal the damage.

Also, be sure to keep lightning or ice arrows handy to interrupt their attacks.

With this, I find farming guardian weapons and shields very easy to do.

If you managed to kill off all guardians at all shrines, wait for the next blood moon for them to respawn so you can try again and get more.

Comment: Please list some of these test of strength shrines. Also do they respawn after a blood moon?

Comment: @Coomie There are four of each type of test of strength shrine (minor, modest, major), and yes, the guardian scouts respawn after a blood moon

Answer (score 1):

The Guardian Shield ++ is the only shield the can block guardian beams for the ones in a shrine.
 [Gerudo Highlands](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Gerudo_Highlands), and [Akkala Highlands](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Akkala) are where you can find the Guardian Shield ++

If you want a shield that blocks guardian beams from guardian stalkers (guardians with legs) or the stationary ones, you need and ancient shield obtained from robbie at akkala tech lab.

Ancient Shield:costs 1,000 rupies 
-1 giant ancient core
-15 ancient springs
-10 ancient gears
As far as i know it can block up to 12 beams before breaking.